# Modificar atributo href via jQuery

Tags: jquery

Eu preciso saber como eu faço para alterar os links e imagens de uma página via jQuery.

Eu tenho que fazer atualições dinâmicas em uma determinanda página e preciso criar um script para isso, que altere imagens e links.

Exemplo:

```
<a href="link1"> <img src="imagem1"></a>
<a href="link2"> <img src="imagem2"></a>
```

Tipo, nesse exemplo eu sei que o `href` contém `link1`, `link2` e que a *tag* `img` contém `imagem1`, `imagem2`

Eu preciso saber se consigo criar um *script* que captura a informação que o usuário digitar e faça um rastreio das *tags* e converta automaticamente.

Imagine que o usuário coloque um link http://wikipedia.org.link1, nesse caso ele iria alterar o `href link1`, o mesmo seria para as imagens.

Comment: Modifica sempre para o que está a seguir ao ultimo `.` ? Ou qual é a regra exatamente ?

Comment: A regra seria a seguinte: eu iria criar um campo (caixa de texto) e jogar o caminho das imagens e links que eu gostaria de alterar e esses mesmos dados iriam alterar alterar os dados do index.html.

Tipo, o script iria considerar a informação digitada no campo e fazer uma comparação (tipo um contains no link e imagens), mais ou menos assim.

HTML
<a href="eusouolink1"> <img src="imagem2.png"></a>

Campo Texto
Nesse caso, com o script, o usuário iria atualizar o conteudo com um novo link e imagem, mas que contenha as informações nas tags href e img

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar erros de digitação é bom usar uma outra forma de escolher qual opção alterar. Poderia usar um `select`, por exemplo.

Usando um `select` você pode fazer isso com

1. A função `val` para saber

   - qual o valor existente num `input` onde o usuário digitou. Ex: `var novovalor = $("input").val()`
   - qual o opção escolhida pelo usuário (link1, link2 ...). Ex: `$("select").val()`
2. A função `attr`para modificar o valor de uma propriedade de um elemento. Por exemplo: `$("a:first").attr("href", novovalor)`

Comment: Muito Obrigado, já me ajudou muito :)

Comment: De nada. Se você considerar que a minha resposta solucionou sua dúvida, por favor, escolhe como solução (clica na seta que está embaixo do número de votos). Se ainda tiver alguma dúvida, pergunta aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode alterar com a função attr() do jquery:

```
$('#elemento').attr('href', 'link que será passado')
$('#elemento').attr('src', 'source da imagem')
```

Espero ter ajudado.