# Modificar href com JQuery

Tags: jquery

Beleza Pessoal?

Seguinte, estou quebrando a cabeça a dias e não encontro a solução que preciso. Estou desenvolvendo um site onepage em wordpress. Criei todo as páginas que preciso (index, sobre, contato etc) e estou chamando elas utilizando o load do JQuery. No entanto, não sei JS e JQuery e meu problema é o seguinte:

- Queria mudar o meu href dos menus ex.: meusite/sobre para #sobre. Mas não sei muito de JS nem JQuery. Pergunto se é possível fazer isso? Como posso fazer isso?

Observações:
Fiz dessa forma o href porque pelo que entendi seria melhor para o SEO do site, o "google" iria navegar no meu site pelos links e indexá-lo melhor.
Caso eu esteja errado em alguma coisa aqui, me informem no que e, se possível, como encontro as respostas, até por que não achei muita coisa clara na web.
Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos, estou começando nessa área então qualquer ajuda será muito bem-vinda.

Comment: Tem uma pergunta parecida aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298099/modificar-atributo-href-via-jquery?rq=1. Dê uma olhada para ver se não lhe ajuda.

Comment: Não me ajudou amigo. Acabei tendo que fazer uma gambiarra (na minha opinião, pelo menos). Vou continuar tentando achar a solução. Obrigado.